# MySQL auto_increment getting crazy after massive INSERT

Tags: mysql

I have created a new table (`my_new_table`) with an auto increment PK.

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'my_new_table';
```

Result: `1`, ok.

I `INSERT` into that table 871 values from another table. Then I make any of those two queries:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_new_table;
SELECT count(*) FROM my_new_table;
```

Result: `871`. ok.

But when I check the `AUTO_INCREMENT` again:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'my_new_table';
```

Result: `1024`.

Why the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is `1024` and not `872`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature does not prevent manual insertion.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60295/why-does-auto-increment-jumps-by-more-than-the-number-of-rows-inserted

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeah, but we are not talking about that.

Comment: @PrabhatG Thanks!

Comment: @Avión Fair enough—I can't see you data, inserts or scripts so I have less information than you.

Answer (score 0):

It may possible due to `Mysql` 2 variable `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` values of both these variables are 1 by default. you had made any change of the value.

So please make that value of both this variable `auto_increment_increment`
and `auto_increment_offset` by **`1`**.

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=1;
```

Comment: If I `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` I get `1` and `1`, so both are ok.

Comment: @Avión you can try with `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=872` and then make two entry.Let's see what happened .

Comment: That's what I made in order to maintain the number order, but I want to avoid doing it.

Comment: @Avión Make sure you are not providing value for `AUTO_INCREMENT` field

Comment: @Avión : check out my link in comment. You should find your answer.

Comment: No I'm not, @SagarGangwal. The link that the user Prabhat provided is quite interesting: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60295/why-does-auto-increment-jumps-by-more-than-the-number-of-rows-inserted

Comment: @PrabhatG Link is useful.. `_/\_`